# HttpSession vs RequestDispatcher

Tags: session, servlets, session-variables, session-cookies, requestdispatcher

Please let me help to understand when to use session instead of RequestDispatcher.
So far I have seen I can pass data from servlet to servlet and jsp forwarding the request and It can pretty much distinguish two different request. So when and why should I use Session? Please help me to understand that.

Comment: I guess your question should be sendRedirect vs RequestDispatcher

Comment: No, my question is particularly that one.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is stateless protocol following request/response pattern. It means that you get request from client and send back response. There is no conversational state between client and server.

So if you need to keep conversational state (example : shopping card, wizard, etc.) - you need to recognize your client (understand which request comes from which client). This is what is session used for.

Comment: Thank you very much. You have given a clear satisfactory answer and it's all clear to me.